# Why is the output showing the variable instead of the user input?

Tags: python

When I run this

```
def main():
 Menu = input("Enter drink")
 Menu2 = input("Enter appetizer")
 Menu3 = input("Enter entree")
 Menu4 = input("Enter desert")
 MenuList = ["+Menu1+", "+Menu2+", "+Menu3+","+Menu4+"]
 print(MenuList)
main()
```

The output shows menu(number) instead of the user input. Help is appreciated!

Comment: did you mean to make `MenuList=[Menu, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4]` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
MenuList = [Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, Menu4]
```